# Can i automate this code with a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops

Can i automate this code with a loop?

I am just learning to loop in R...

```
event_loggers_es1$main_door_state[event_loggers_es1$main_door_state == "0"] <- "1"
event_loggers_es2$bathroom_door_state[event_loggers_es2$bathroom_door_state == "0"] <- "1"
event_loggers_es3$bedroom_door_state[event_loggers_es3$bedroom_door_state == "0"] <- "1"
event_loggers_es4$bedroom_window_state[event_loggers_es4$bedroom_window_state == "0"] <- "1"
event_loggers_es5$living_door_state[event_loggers_es5$living_door_state == "0"] <- "1"
event_loggers_es6$living_window_state[event_loggers_es6$living_window_state == "0"] <- "1"
event_loggers_es7$balcony_door_state[event_loggers_es7$balcony_door_state == "0"] <- "1"
```

Comment: A bit more information could help here. :) If the various event_loggers_esn df's are in a list, and the mentioned variables are always the first column for instance, then you could iterate through the list.

Comment: Yes, you can. Do you have a more specific quesion?

Comment: What is your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following might work:

```
room_types=c('main_door_state','bathroom_door_state',....)
for(i in 1:7){
    df=get(paste0('event_loggers_es',i)) #store data of interest in one variable
    column_of_interest=df[,colnames(df)==room_types[i]] # specify col
    column_of_interest[column_of_interest == "0"] <- "1" #correction
    df[,colnames(df)==room_types[i]]=column_of_interest # reassign corrected column to df
    assign(paste0('event_loggers_es',i),df) #reassign new df to original 'event_loggers_es*'
}
```

However I think you can have the code go through the data in a better way than how your doing it currently... Such as the way that's recommended in the comments.

Or maybe, if your datasets are each in separate CSV files- you could loop through them that way.

For example: let's say that you have the data already in separate CSV files (I'm guessing that's what you have...)- you could then do something like:

```
for(i in 1:7){
    df=read.csv(paste0('data_file_',i,'.csv')) #loop through files in directory
    #.... then do something with df...
}
```

I think the above might be better than storing different data frames in memory as 1,2,3...7 
Hope this helps.